# Getting an error while upgrading an MSI application

Tags: upgrade, windows-update, installshield-2013

I'm getting below error while upgrading one software on my Windows 2003 server.

> "Error 1260 : Windows cannot open this program because it has been prevented by a software restriction policy. For more information, open event viewer."

I searched lot on internet and one thing I got to know that, this error occurs because of one Windows's security update, KB2918614. I uninstalled that update & tried upgrade of my product, it worked fine for me.

But my question is, without uninstalling that update how I can make my upgrade of software successful ?

Here are some logs that I'm getting while failure :

> MSI (s) (E4:24) [10:39:07:097]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\SourceHash{97353D18-281D-42B5-8855-21E08089EFB8}
>
> MSI (s) (E4:24) [10:39:07:128]: SECREPAIR: CryptAcquireContext succeeded
>
> MSI (s) (E4:24) [10:39:07:878]: SECREPAIR: filename: **********.msi Stored Hash Value:+VE6k8PVr******************RjSWBjatbw= Current Hash:jhsyK1CivGh*************V2MlyUZsICUx83w=
>
> MSI (s) (E4:24) [10:39:07:878]: SECREPAIR: UAC not supported and could not take approval from user
>
> MSI (s) (E4:24) [10:39:07:878]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 4ec4E6A3388

Comment: No one has any answer for this ?? No one had gone through such issue !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer !!
There is one more update Microsoft provided to get rid from current security update KB2918614.   [Here is the Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918614)

In this article they have mentioned some registry changes. After doing those change my issue got resolved. Here are those registry changes :

> Locate and then click the following subkey in the registry:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer
>
> On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>
> Type SecureRepairPolicy for the name of the DWORD, and then press Enter.
>
> Right-click SecureRepairPolicy, and then click Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type 2, and then click OK.
>
> Locate and then click the following subkey in the registry:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer
>
> On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click Key.
>
> Type SecureRepairWhitelist for the name of the key, and then press Enter.
>
> Double-click the SecureRepairWhitelist key to open it.
>
> On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click String Value. Create String Values that contain the product codes (including braces {}) of the products that have to be added to the Safe Recipients list.